# Print in single Pthread

Tags: c, pthreads

I'm trying to implement a program using Pthreads in C. Now, I've tried to let a single thread print "Hi":

```
void * generator(void *arguments){
     printf("Hi");
     return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, const char* argv[]){
     pthread_create(&threads_ids[0], NULL, &generator, NULL);=
}
```

This doesn't work and doesn't print anything. However, when I put the creation of the pthread in a for loop it does print "Hi", but at each execution the occurrence differs.

Is this normal behaviour, and if so; how can I fix it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Add a newline to the output format.   Messages don't appear otherwise (unless you flush them).  And use `int main(void)` when you're ignoring the command line arguments.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's because your main thread returns and thus exits the process. It means the thread you created never gets a chance to run.

Unlike just returning from main(), calling `pthread_exit(0)` from main(), will let the other thread continue executing.

Alternatively, you can wait for the thread to complete execution by calling `pthread_join()` on the thread you created.

When you execute in a loop, probably some of the threads you create gets executed before main thread exits, and thus appears to "work" (prints some `Hi`).
But it does have the same problem as the code you posted.