# Invalid initializer when passing a struct as a void* pointer

Tags: c, pointers, struct, pthreads, void

I'm trying to pass a struct to a function in order to take advantage of multithreading in C. I don't really understand how it works, so I've just tried various syntaxes which give a variety of error messages, so I'm not sure if my particular query has been answered before. I put together the most simple code I can which resembles what I want to do, and it still gives me an error, even if I set it up to match similar examples on this site which apparently have worked for people. I'm hoping I'm just missing something quite simple. Anyway here's the code which won't compile:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
    int i_start;
    int i_end;
} my_struct;

void *func(void *ptr) {

    int j_start;
    int j_end;

    my_struct input = (my_struct *) ptr;
    j_start = input.i_start;
    j_end = input.i_end;
    printf("%d %d\n", j_start, j_end);

}

int main() {
    my_struct qwerty;

    qwerty.i_start = 0;
    qwerty.i_end = 1;

    pthread_t tid;

    pthread_create(&tid, NULL, func, &qwerty);

    return 0;
}
```

This particular code gives me a compilation error:

```
test.c: In function 'func':
test.c:14:20: error: invalid initializer
  my_struct input = (my_struct *) ptr;
```

Like I said, I've tried a few different things but I can't get it right. Thanks for any help.

Comment: `my_struct input = (my_struct *) ptr;` --> `my_struct input = *(my_struct *) ptr;`. Also `func` must return a value.

Comment: Learning C by experimentation will lead you to the place you don't want to get.

Comment: Additionally, you may face another problem: main thread might exit before the func thread could start or complete. See this on [how to address it](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40514326/1275169).

Comment: Read [ask] and follow the advice. Note: C is definitively a bad idea for trial&error! Get a good book and learn the language properly.

Answer (score 2):

> `my_struct input = (my_struct *) ptr;`

The type of `input` is `my_struct`, and you're trying to assign a `my_struct *` value (a pointer to a `my_struct`) to it.  The types must match.

Try using a pointer type and dereferencing it (to get a plain `my_struct` value):

```
my_struct *input = (my_struct *) ptr;
j_start = (*input).i_start;
j_end = (*input).i_end;
```

Or using the pointer itself with the arrow operator:

```
my_struct *input = (my_struct *) ptr;
j_start = input->i_start;
j_end = input->i_end;
```

Or you can dereference before assignment:

```
my_struct input = *((my_struct *) ptr);
j_start = input.i_start;
j_end = input.i_end;
```

This syntax can be confusing, so be sure to look up how the `*` operator works and how it is different from the `*` used in the variable type.